# How to control the div or box around an element

Tags: html, css

I'm Looking to control the box around the `<ul><li> <a href=''>Register</li></ul>`. 
I've made a greenish background around that list item but I'd like to control the top of the border and bottom border to bring them closer to the text *Register*

To be honest, the left and right sides were also to far out and I'm not sure how I inadvertently fix them. Didn't notice the change till just now.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

body {
    background-color: #37acc5;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#top {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

header {
    float: left;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #262626;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;

}

header h1 {
    color: #262626;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

#nav-top {
    float: right;
    min-height: 50px;
}

#list1 li {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#id-top-nav-link {
    float: left;
}

#id-select select {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 17px;
}

#top-link div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.nav .div-list .list > li {
    padding-left: 15px;
}

#list1 #register {
    background-color: #37acc5;
    border-radius: 10%;
}

#article {
    background-image: url('../img/blockchain.jpg');
    background-position: 0%;
    padding: 100px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

#article div {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

#art-text {
    background-color: #37acc5;
}

article h1, h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

#footer1 {
    float: left;
}

#footer2 {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
<!-----------------------------------HEADER------------------------------------------->
<div id="top">
    <header id="header">
        <h1>Icon Share</h1>
    </header>
    <!-----------------------------------NAV---------------------------------------------->
    <nav id="nav-top" class="nav">
        <div id="top-link">
            <div class="div-list" id="id-top-nav-link">
                <ul class="list" id="list1">
                    <li id="register"><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="id-select">
                <select>
                    <option value="english">English</option>
                    <option value="chinese">Chinese</option>
                    <option value="spanish">Spanish</option>
                    <option value="portugese">Portugese</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<!----------------------------------MAIN---------------------------------------------->
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the following changes for your desired look and feel.
In the CSS, make the following changes:

```
#list1 li {

    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKeUi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjy1z.png)

Answer (score 1):

your problem can be solved by simply decrease the padding in the list item or in the 
 a element. the border will get closer to the text.
`#register{`
`padding: 0;`
`}`
or (prefer it)
`a{`
`padding: 0;`
`}`